# Yii 2: Pass Session Variable to Input

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How do I pass the session variable `userid` to a text input? Using `Yii::app->session`?

loginform model of my application

```
 $session = Yii::$app->session;
 $session->set('userid',  $this->getUser($this->email, 'id'));
 $session->set('firstname',  $this->getUser($this->email, 'fname'));
```

view/ form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['value' => Yii::$app->session['email']]) ?>
```

Comment: Please accept the edit, so the answer can pass under the correct category and be easier reachable by people who might have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass it as `Yii::$app->session->get('userid')->id`.

You were calling the `email` instead of `userid`. You can read more about sessions it in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session) itself. Please, let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: am getting an error "  Object of class app\models\Users could not be converted to string "  I have a model users that has users details.   in this line   "                            
            `` ` <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['value' =>Yii::$app->session->get('userid')]) ?>     
"```

Comment: This is my getUser function .```public function getUser($email,$column)
    {
        $userinfo = Users::find()->where(['id'=>$email])->asArray()->one();
        if(!empty($userinfo))
       
           return $userdetails[$column];
        else
            return 'undefined';```
    }         it is giving the sane error after changing it...

Comment: @rabin254 I am not sure how this works, though, as in the getUser() function you are returning `$userdetails`, while the data is in `$userinfo`. Are you sure it is the right function?

Comment: Then how should it be

Comment: @rabin254 If this is the entire function `$userdetails` should be `null` and not have anything in it. You are storing the data in `$userInfo`, so that is the correct variable to use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you pass the value to the session. Because the value you are passing is an object, but there is a solution and it is simple.

```
$form->field($model, 'name')->textInput([
    'value' => Yii::$app->session->get('userid')->id
]);
```

Comment: @LucasEmanuel My answer is literally the same + it has more information and an actual bugfix and it is there for longer + has helpful comments below it.

Comment: There are 40 seconds in between the edit and and answer. I was making a big edit as you can see in the history. I started my edit before you posted your answer, so I did not see your answer. I am not saying you copied your answer from me, but that my answer has more information and therefor better for helping other people.

Comment: Thank you @rabin254, I hope my answer helps others

Comment: Next to the answer

Comment: why is it giving me this error please[Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
]? I have changed everything and it is not working. ```<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput([
    'value' => Yii::$app->session->get('userid')->id
])?>```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear why you want to expressly set the session user ID when Yii has a built-in way to retrieve the user ID.

```
Yii::$app->user->getId();
```

The above will return the user ID without the need for you to manually set the session user ID.

Comment: I have a form that once  you login to the system you are supposed to fill and submit and  the session will help to know who did this .

Comment: it is not working. Wanted to auto generate the user id in the textiput but it is not working?

Comment: First check that the command works: echo Yii::$app->user->getId(); exit(); if you see the user ID then at least you know it works.

Comment: Unless you specifically want the user to see their own name, you don’t need to include it in the form. You can simply populate the model from the controller action after the form is submitted. This is much safer (otherwise the user could override the user ID assignment which would make your form more susceptible to hacking)